# How to read cells from xlsx

Tags: java, excel, linux, apache-poi

I need to read cells from XLSX. I use Apache POI, but I don't know what the mistake is.

This is my code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class miniwolfi {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File excel = new File("/tmp/table.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        
        double result = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
        System.out.println(result);
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

And the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/таблица.xlsx (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at miniwolfi.main(miniwolfi.java:17)
```

Maybe mistake is the way to XLSX. How can I fix this?

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. There is no file `/tmp/таблица.xlsx`. But the exception does not fit to your provided code. The code tries opening file `/tmp/table.xlsx`. So this code cannot throw that exception. Please show the code which throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file is xlsx or xls files first, and you have permissions,

Your error is the file is not found

I would write it as follow and use try-with-resources

```
        File excel = new File("/tmp/table.xlsx");
        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);){
           XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
              
           double result = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
           System.out.println(result);
      }
```

Comment: the way to the file is correct?

Comment: The file name in the code is not the same as the exception is there an issue with special chars?